# SharePoint Lync Presence issues

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, presence-indication

I have an issue with the user presence icon, showing/not showing.

Some information:
I have a custom master-page.
Issue is in libraries in a site collection.
The presence icons show in people search results for the same people where it doesnt work in the library under the column checked out to -the column has the presence part.
The web application has presence and smart tagging enabled.

This is what I have tried:
I have tried applying V4 masterpage-no help
I have made absolutely sure that custom masterpage does not override the ProcessImnMarkers() method, I have replaced the Java Script code you supplied in another post [IM Presence Icons not appearing in SOME master pages - IE9](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27554/im-presence-icons-not-appearing-in-some-master-pages-ie9), and replaced it in the INIT.js file-no help.

When I check the html using F12 in the library the  tag of the icon does not have the onload="IMNRC" bit that the search page has and its alt parameter says the following: "No Presence Information"

So what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Steven,

You said you have applied v4.master and still had no luck with some of these pages?  That is the standard SharePoint 2010 master page, so it should work.  Are the people you are looking at logged into Lync?  If they are not, their presence icons will not show up in lists and libraries.  You should still be able to click in the blank space where the icon should be, however, and get all of the standard Presence options.  From my experience I will claim that the Search Results page uses a different mechanism for loading presence icons (perhaps different settings on the ASP.NET/SharePoint user control that creates the icons) than other places within SharePoint.

Looking at offline users in my own document libraries with the dev tools, my comment above seems to be validated.  The offline users also had "No presence information" in their alt tags, but I was still able to click the blank image and send an email or offline IM, etc.

I do not know if you have already looked at this or how you got your custom master page going, but I have found Randy Drisgill's starter master pages to be extremely helpful with my own work:  http://startermasterpages.codeplex.com/

Regards,

- Matt

Comment: Hi Matt, seems like the issue was on AD. the presence information was limited to a few people. The problem was that these AD account had duplicate email address is AD, and for some reason The presence information did not show with these users. the fix was deleted the AD accounts and everything started working.

Comment: Ah, yeah there are a lot of quirky things that can happen with AD that mess up SharePoint in different ways.  It is actually kind of unpleasant sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share my solution to this issue. I discovered that the custom master that we purchased was overriding the ProcessImn() and ProcessImnMarkers() Methods. Once they were commented out, Lync presence started working.

To check to see if your Master page is the issue, switch the master page to be either Oslo or Seattle [OOB].